# R - Stepwise random results

Tags: r, logistic-regression

If I set a seed before the regression (logistic)

```
lr = glm(target ~ 1, family=binomial, data = X)
set.seed(12345)
lr = stepAIC(lr, scope = f, family=binomial, data = X, k = 3)
summary(lr)
```

I get different results depending on the seed with different performance. Which one is the random part of the algorithm? Because in a neural net the result depends on the first weights if it does have local minima, but in a logistic regression what is the random part?

(Since it is a conceptual question I didn't add a reproducible example.)

Comment: are you sure that you didnt do the search with the new seed on the new overwritten `lr` output (your original and stepAIC models are both called `lr`)

Comment: @user20650  the first model is only the intercept, should be always the same, or not?

Comment: yes., it should be the same.. my point was getting different results is unexpected.. i thought a potential reason was when you did the second search (using `stepAIC(lr ..`) you are using the `lr` produced from the previous stepwise model, rather than the original glm model, as you overwrite it. Hence different results

Comment: object is the initial model in the stepwise search. that is the first lr and it's used as a parameter in the stepAIC.

Comment: no, the object , the first argument, to stepAIC  is the initial model - lr in this case -  which may have been written over

Comment: I know you think this is a conceptual question, but it looks like a workflow problem to experienced R users (AFAIK you're right that there is no random component to `stepAIC`).  Therefore, we would like to see a reproducible example if possible ...